# Importing a Components index into my different screens/pages?

Tags: reactjs, import, directory, export

This might be trivial for you but it's my first react project and I'm struggling structuring it with export/import. Here is the situation.

I have different folders in my project
[image]

I created a **Components.js** index to gather all my components and export them all to the different **screens**.
[image]

I then would like to import the components I need in a specific page (ex: homepage)
[image]

But it is NOT WORKING !
I get this error in the console :

ERROR in ./src/screens/website/homepage/Homepage.js 5:0-57
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Components' in '/Users/maxime/acacia/src/screens/website/homepage'
resolve './components/Components' in '/Users/maxime/acacia/src/screens/website/homepage'
using description file: /Users/maxime/acacia/package.json (relative path: ./src/screens/website/homepage)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
using description file: /Users/maxime/acacia/package.json (relative path: ./src/screens/website/homepage/components/Components)
no extension
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
/Users/maxime/acacia/src/screens/website/homepage/components/Components doesn't exist
.web.mjs

I think it has something to do with the import module of the homepage (**import {NavBar, Footer} from "./components/Components"**) but I can't figure it out.
Thanks for your help,
Max

Comment: try this.
Export - export * from './NavBar';
Import - import { NavBar } from 'path/component.ts'

Comment: can you please provide sandbox or stackblitz link ?

Comment: Working with the answer below. Thanks Piyush!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Homepage.js` you are trying to import from `./components/Components` which essentially resolves to `src/screens/website/homepage/components/Components`. In your case, as I see, this directory is located elsewhere, so if you change your import to:

`import {NavBar, Footer} from "../../../components/Components";`

the problem should get resolved.

What you can also do is rename `Components.js` to `index.js` so that when you import from it you won't have to repeat yourself (you will have to change the imports from that file everywhere if you rename it).

They would look like this (using the current example):

`import {NavBar, Footer} from "../../../components";`

You can go the extra mile and configure absolute imports for your react project, so that you don't have to type `../` or `../../../` when importing from distant directories.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports